# Postback without a control context

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

I have a situation where I want to use several server side controls, which have clients side state.  I want to check the state when events occur (like various clicks), and when the state is where i want it, I want to postback to the server and do some processing.

In particular, I need to make sure that at least 3 different controls have selections before I want to do a postback.  Since there is no specific control that will initiate the postback, I just want to capture the selection events on the client side, then call __doPostBack() (or something similar) to initiate the processing.  So i have disabled all server side events, turned off autopostback, and have wired up some javascript to handle this.

I've got all the client side code written and working, however I cannot seem to get the server-side to recognize the postback.  I'm overriding RaisePostBackEvent, and checking the eventArgument for my custom argument.  This doesn't work, as RaisePostBackEvent is never called.

This method has worked when I had autopostback enabled (for example, the Telerik Radgrid OnSelectChanged server side event).

Any suggestions on the best way to handle this?

Update:

When asked for sample code, it's exactly as I say above.  Not rocket science.

Javascript:

```
function CheckState(source, eventArgs) {
    // logic to test state of controls
    __doPostBack("", "DoMyWork:");
}
```

Then in code behind I have:

```
protected override void RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler source, string eventArgument)
{
    if (eventArgument.IndexOf("DoMyWork") != -1)
    {
        // do my server side work.
    }
}
```

RESOLUTION:

Because this is somewhat confusing.. I'll just say what my solution was.

I used one of the controls involved in the postback and used it's UniqueID for the control parameter, then my method as the event.

Comment: consider using AJAX, there are a number of AJAX libraries that can perform the tasks for you much easier than writing you own JavaScript. But, if you must use your own script + postback, would you mind to post the code you have so far?

Comment: Ajax will probably happen down the road, but for now i'm avoiding it due to the complexity of the state conditions.  I also throw up a curtain to prevent users from changing control state while it's processing, and I don't currently want to deal with making that work with ajax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you call the __doPostBack() without parameters, asp.net cannot figure out which control fired the event and thus it cannot determine which event to fire. 
you need to add the name of the control as a parameter to __doPostBack() and an argument which could be null if you dont need one

```
__doPostBack('textbox1','')  //no arguments

__doPostBack('textbox1','12')
```

you can read the argument you passed in from code behind like this:

```
Dim arg As String = Request("__EVENTARGUMENT")
```

Comment: There is no specific control involved.  It's several controls.  Even so, i've tried using one of the controls as the first parameter and it still doesn't call RaisePostBackEvent, which has worked for other code.

Comment: you can create a new control and make it hidden and use pass its name in the dopostback, then it will call its event handler. note that you need to pass the name of the control not its id. set a breakpoint on the control to grab its name

Comment: That was it, I was using ClientID rather than UniqueID.  UniqueID causes the event to fire.  Thanks.